# How to detect the edges of certain objects

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I recently decided to teach myself computer vision, so I only know the fundamentals of image processing. I have decided to attempt a hopefully simple exercise: **detect the tiles** in pictures similar to this one:

[image: Tiles]

I am aware I can use the Hough transform to find the circles in each tile, and I'll use that to make the algorithm more robust later on, but at the moment I am struggling to find the contours of the tiles.

My first attempt has been to resize the image, blur it, make it grayscale and apply canny. Then, tiles are those contours which have four sides and a certain aspect ratio. This works fine for most tiles in most pictures, but in this one it seems to fail on the top one because of the white speaker in the background (it does not think it has four sides):

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred_gray, 75, 200)
cv2.imshow("Edged", edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Canny detection]

I then discovered [image pyramids](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_pyramids/py_pyramids.html) and decided to give it a go by blurring my image and then substracting from it a blurred interpolated version from a higher level of the pyramid, and while the edges are more defined now, the rugosities of the background have been highlighted as well:

```
blurred_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(
    cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), (5, 5), 0)
blurred_gray_recons = cv2.pyrUp(cv2.pyrDown(blurred_gray))
edged = blurred_gray - blurred_gray_recons
cv2.imshow('Edged', edged)
```

[image: Gaussian difference]

**How could I reliably perform edge detection in these cases?** Please note that the background won't always be of the same color.

Comment: As we can see, the tiles are so white compared to the background. So, try to threshold the original (blured) gray image, so we can seperate the highlight tiles region.

Comment: @Silencer Thought of that, but in general the background won't always be so clearly different from the tiles.

Comment: In images with dynamic backgrounds, thresholding and edge detection seldom give good results. Using neural networks and/or feature based detection give better results.

Comment: @Zindarod My plan is not to rely exclusively on edge detection, but combine it with Hough transform for other feature detection, use the aspect ratio of the tiles... I appreciate the advice and I'll look into it, but I'm just learning the basics, so I was hoping there was an easier solution.

Comment: In your second approach you are performing an [unsharp masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking) that enhances noise in your case. If you are using Canny, this [robust threshold estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Robust_method_to_determine_the_dual-threshold_value) might be useful. Other methods you can try with `opencv` include morphological operations (closing followed by opening with increasing kernel radius) for flattening the background texture, [MSER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions)s, clustering (e.g. kmeans) etc.

Comment: The tiles are white on a dark background. So thresholding on the tile color and some morphology (or contour filtering) to remove any dark inside will create a mask. From that you can isolate each tile if you want and then find the numbers inside.  Edge detection is a poor way to go.

Answer (score 0):

edge in an image is the abrupt change of pixel intensity values. For the edge detection there are many approaches like gradient based and hassian based. In the gradient based there are two methods: one is 1st derivative and 2nd derivative and for hassian also two techniques are there which is laplacian and canny edge detector. Canny edge detector algorithm is very famous for edge detection where first we need to smooth the image using any filter like gaussian and then we need to calculate the gradient calculation which gives the magnitude and orientation(direction) of edge. After that suppress the non-maximum gradients by retaining only the local maxima and last we need to apply hysteresis thresholding for edge tracking.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35617403)